# Enum Identifiable in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to conform my enum Sheets to Identifiable. This means, I must implement the id property and return it.

```
struct Product: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let price: Double
}

enum Sheets: Identifiable {
    case add
    case edit(Product)

    var id: Int {
       hashValue
     }
}
```

The above implementation does not work and an error says that hashValue is undefined. The other implementation I used is as follows:

```
enum Sheets: Identifiable {
    case add
    case edit(Product)
    
    var id: Int {
        switch self {
            case .add:
                return 1
            case .edit(_):
                return 2
        }
    }
    
}
```

This does return a stable identity. Is this the recommended way to solve the problem of creating a stable identity for my enum cases.

Comment: I think if you make it `CaseIterable` you don't have to define an ID or make it identifiable. That's just a guess however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on `Sheets` purpose and usage, so yes, if there would be only two variants, e.g. menu item > view type, then your variant would be enough.

If you would want complete uniqueness including sheet/product combination, then I recommend something like below

```
struct Product: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString           // << here !!
    let name: String
    let price: Double
}

enum Sheets: Identifiable {
    case add
    case edit(Product)

    var id: String {
        switch self {
            case .add:
                return "1"
            case .edit(let product):
                return "2.\(product.id)"     // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: hash is not enough for identity (hash guaranties difference if two items gives different hashes, but two different items could produce same hash, even with low probability)

Comment: I know this has been accepted already but I have a question. For the second switch case, will it be okay to just return "\(product.id)". Basically removing the "2." from it. Since, productId will always be different for each product.

Comment: Sure, that was just a demo.

Comment: Thanks! In your answer you wrote "If you would want complete uniqueness including sheet/product combination". Can you think of a scenario where, I would want complete uniqueness to control my sheets.

Comment: if your `product.id` happens to be equal `1` then it results in `.add` because it is the first in switch.